# Running two process on Flask with common variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, web-applications, web-deployment

I want to build a Webapp with Flask where some data is printed on a dynamic page in real time.

The data is taken from a Python script which connects to a Websocket, then it's printed on the frontend with Flask.

I have two problems:
1) I can't run both the scripts together
2) I don't know how to call `parsed` from `test` to `yield`

Here is the code:

```
from time import sleep
from flask import Flask, render_template
import websocket
from bitmex_websocket import Instrument
from bitmex_websocket.constants import InstrumentChannels
from bitmex_websocket.constants import Channels
import json
from threading import Thread, Event

app = Flask(__name__)

websocket.enableTrace(True)

channels = [
    InstrumentChannels.trade,
]


XBTUSD = Instrument(symbol='XBTUSD',
                    channels=channels)
XBTUSD.on('action', lambda msg: test(msg))

def test(msg):
    parsed = json.loads(json.dumps(msg))
    print(parsed)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # render the template (below) that will use JavaScript to read the stream
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/stream_sqrt')
def stream():
    def generate():   
        yield '{}\n'.format('test')

    return app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text/plain')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    XBTUSD.run_forever()
    app.run()
```

If i put `XBTUSD.run_forever()` before `app.run()` i will start the part supposed to retrieve the data but the Flask app won't start. If i do the opposite, the Flask app will run but not the other part. How can i run together the whole app? How could i "share" variables between `test` and `generate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to go, please use flask-socketio instead flask. 
https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Sample for sending messages using flask-socketio
https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sending-messages

Comment: Hey! Yes, i tried to re-make my app with SocketIO a while ago but i have the same problem, however since you are not the first telling me to use it, i'll stick to it :)